# How to avoid redundancy in a JSON file?

Tags: json

I've a use case where I need to define a json configuration to determine the key for a given set of dimensions. The config looks like this:

```
{
 "foo": {
  "bar": {
    "a": "abc",
  },
  "car": {
    "a": "xyz",
  },
  "dar": {
    "a": "abc"
  }
}
```

How can I specify "abc" at the start of the JSON and re-use it? The above example if a small config. I may end up having a large config file. This will help keep the config consistent in case of future updates. Is this possible with JSON or should I be exploring other options?

Just to clarify, my question is about avoiding redundancy in the json configurations, and not in the schema.

Comment: Since JSON itself doesn't support this kind of abstraction, you need a different format from which you can *generate* your JSON file.

Comment: Unfortunately, the serialized JSON is expected to be hard-coded, written by a human. The generation part would be super easy if we're using a programming interface for it. (:

Comment: What is your environment that it can distinguish between a person typing and the output of a program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON itself doesn't support anything like JSON Schema references.

You can use [jsonnet](http://jsonnet.org/learning/tutorial.html) to reference or include other files, but I've not used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

The `definitions` keyword is designed for this use case.

Here's an example from the linked specification document:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/positiveInteger" },
    "definitions": {
        "positiveInteger": {
            "type": "integer",
            "exclusiveMinimum": 0
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, where a subschema would have been defined for the value of `items`, the schema defined in `definitions/positiveInteger` is now being referenced.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-9

Note: You can only use references for where you would otherwise have a subschema. You cannot reference data, for example the value of an enum.

Further reading: http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html

Comment: Thanks! I did review json schema documentation before posting the question. (: 
While it is easy to re-use fields in the schema. I'm unaware of the actual configuration file itself containing any re-usability.

Comment: Configuration file?

Comment: I mean, the configuration itself(assuming it is stored in a file). What I mean is that I want re-usability in the configuration.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by "configuration" in this context. I only showed JSON Schema. `definitions` is a JSON Schema keyword designed to help enable reuse within the schema. Can you explain what you mean by "configuration"? I don't see any configuration, file or otherwise, here.

Comment: So, the schema is actually used to define the expected structure of a JSON. Where as, I'm more interested in the reuse in the serialized JSON itself.

Comment: Oh. So let me check I understand. You have a JSON file, and you see how JSON Schema has references, and you want to use references in your JSON file, right? Well JSON doesn't support that. I know you can use jsonnet to reference or include other files, but I've not used it. You'd have to read the docs at https://jsonnet.org/learning/tutorial.html

Comment: It would mean your source JSON is de duplicated, but you'd still generate duplicated JSON files for others to use. Just how it is.

Comment: I love jsonnet! Thanks for the recommendation! Please can you add that as an answer? Even if I end up not using it for this particular use-case, I think it effectively answers my question and I can use it for future use-cases. (:

Comment: Done. StackOverflow considers asking for a library or off site resource as "off-topic", but given you didn't do that in this question, I consider it valid, and so have done as you've asked and added another question. I'll leave my other question as is, in case search foo leads people here who have the problem I believed you to have.

Answer (score 0):

Since JSON itself doesn't support this kind of abstraction, what you need is a way to *generate* a JSON file from something that does. Let me suggest [Dhall](https://dhall-lang.org):

Your template (stored in `tmp.dhall`) might look like

```
let abc_val = "abc"
in {
   foo = {
      bar = {a = abc},
      car = {a = "xyz"},
      dar = {a = abc}
   }
}
```

Then you would use `dhall-to-json` to produce a JSON file (`jq` being used only to pretty-print the result).

```
$ dhall-to-json < tmp.dhall | jq .
{
  "foo": {
    "dar": {
      "a": "abc"
    },
    "car": {
      "a": "xyz"
    },
    "bar": {
      "a": "abc"
    }
  }
}
```